# 64-bit Code Cave Returning Incorrect Entry Point Location

Tags: c++, c, windows, security, code-injection

I have been attempting to run a 64-bit DLL purely in a processes virtual memory *without* 'manually mapping' it (i.e. manually resolving relocations/imports).

The plan was to inject code into the target application and load the module via conventional means, such as LoadLibrary.

I was under the assumption LoadLibrary would fix the module relocations/imports on it's own, as that's what it is designed to do.

After loading the module, the injected code would obtain information regarding the module with GetModuleInformation, transfer it to a temporary memory buffer, free the module, allocate memory at the same address it was originally loaded at, write it back, and execute the entry point.

That last step is where I believe the error is occurring.

In order to test this theory, I have hard-coding entry point addresses, debugged the remote application via Visual Studio's 'Attach to Process' feature, emulated a similar environment to correct bad pointer arithmetic, all in order to gain a bit more information on what the error might be.

---

**Here is some general information which may or may not be useful:**

- Both applications (the injector, and DLL) are compiled to run in 64-bit architectures
- The test application I have been using to test the injection method is the windows update applicaiton (wuauclt.exe - located in /System32/), it is of course compiled to run as a 64-bit PE
- Host machine: Windows 7 Home Premium (system type: 64-bit operating system)

**As far as information relating directly to the injector goes:**

- The primary code injection method works (as far as I can tell), and I have proven this via caveman debugging with MessageBoxA
- The project is using a multi-byte character set with code optimizations disabled. The code was compiled using VS 2013 Ultimate (both projects built for Release x64)
- SDL checks are off since unsafe functions are used (strcpy and friends)
- The injector is debugged with elevated privileges (as high as SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGES) every time its ran.

**Code Preface**:
The code exhibited below is not in any which way meant to look *pretty* or exhibit *good* programming practices. Keep this in mind when viewing the code. It was specifically designed to test a code-injection method to verify it works. If you have issues with the program layout, structure, etc, feel free to correct them and/or restructure them on your own. It's not the reason I'm here. Unless it is what resulted in the error, then it is entirely the reason I'm here :)

**The code for the injector:** http://pastebin.com/FF5G9nnR

```
/*
    Some of the code was truncated (functions not pertaining to the injection), but
    I have verified the code compiles and works correctly with it's injeteme.dll counterpart
*/

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>

#define TARGET_PID                1124

typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pFreeLibrary)(HMODULE);
typedef HMODULE(WINAPI* pLoadLibraryA)(LPCSTR);
typedef HANDLE(WINAPI* pGetCurrentProcess)(void);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* DLL_MAIN)(HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID);
typedef HANDLE(WINAPI* pOpenProcess)(DWORD, BOOL, DWORD);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pVirtualFree)(LPVOID, SIZE_T, DWORD);
typedef int(__stdcall* pMessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
typedef LPVOID(WINAPI* pVirtualAlloc)(LPVOID, SIZE_T, DWORD, DWORD);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pGetModuleInformation)(HANDLE, HMODULE, LPMODULEINFO, DWORD);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* pWriteProcessMemory)(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T*);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct IINFO
{
    LPVOID stubAddr;
    LPVOID retStatusPtr;
    char fullModulePath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pId, sizeOfCurrStruct;

    // DEBUG
    pMessageBoxA messageBox;

    pOpenProcess openProcess;
    pVirtualFree virtualFree;
    pFreeLibrary freeLibrary;
    pLoadLibraryA loadLibrary;
    pVirtualAlloc virtualAlloc;
    pGetCurrentProcess getCurrProc;
    pWriteProcessMemory writeMemory;
    pGetModuleInformation getModInfo;
};

static DWORD WINAPI stub(IINFO *iInfo)
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    MODULEINFO mInfo;
    DLL_MAIN dllMain;
    LPVOID lpNewMod, lpTempModBuff;

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pIDH;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pINH;

    iInfo->messageBox(NULL, iInfo->fullModulePath, NULL, 0);

    hMod = iInfo->loadLibrary(iInfo->fullModulePath);
    if (!hMod)
        return 0;

    if (!iInfo->getModInfo(iInfo->getCurrProc(), hMod, &mInfo, sizeof(MODULEINFO)))
        return 0;

    lpTempModBuff = iInfo->virtualAlloc(NULL, mInfo.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!lpTempModBuff)
        return 0;
    if (!iInfo->writeMemory(iInfo->getCurrProc(), lpTempModBuff, mInfo.lpBaseOfDll, mInfo.SizeOfImage, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (!iInfo->freeLibrary(hMod))
        return 0;

    lpNewMod = iInfo->virtualAlloc(mInfo.lpBaseOfDll, mInfo.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!lpNewMod)
        return 0;

    // using wpm since we have already acquired the function
    if (!iInfo->writeMemory(iInfo->getCurrProc(), lpNewMod, lpTempModBuff, mInfo.SizeOfImage, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (!iInfo->virtualFree(lpTempModBuff, 0, MEM_RELEASE))
        return 0;

    /*if (!iInfo->virtualFree(iInfo, 0, MEM_RELEASE))
    return 0;
    iInfo->messageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0); */

    pIDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpNewMod;
    if (!pIDH)
        return 0;
    pINH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)lpNewMod + pIDH->e_lfanew);
    if (!pINH)
        return 0;
    dllMain = (DLL_MAIN)((LPBYTE)lpNewMod + pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
    if (!dllMain)
        return 0;
    iInfo->messageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
    dllMain((HINSTANCE)lpNewMod, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);
    return 1;
}
static DWORD WINAPI stubEnd(){ return 0; }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread = 0;
    DWORD dwStubSize = 0;
    int sucResp = 0, count = 0;
    HMODULE hUser32 = 0, hNtdll = 0;
    char fullPathName[] = "C:\\injectme.dll";

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TARGET_PID);
    if (!hProc || hProc == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    __int64 SizeOfStub = (LPBYTE)stubEnd - (LPBYTE)stub;
    LPVOID lpStub = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, SizeOfStub, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!lpStub)
        return 0;

    hUser32 = LoadLibraryA("user32.dll");
    if (!hUser32)
        return 0;
    hNtdll = LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
    if (!hNtdll)
        return 0;

    IINFO iInfo = {};
    iInfo.retStatusPtr = &sucResp;
    strcpy(iInfo.fullModulePath, fullPathName);
    iInfo.sizeOfCurrStruct = sizeof(IINFO);
    iInfo.stubAddr = lpStub;
    iInfo.pId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    iInfo.messageBox = (pMessageBoxA)GetProcAddress(hUser32, "MessageBoxA");
    iInfo.openProcess = (pOpenProcess)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "OpenProcess");
    iInfo.virtualFree = (pVirtualFree)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "VirtualFree");
    iInfo.freeLibrary = (pFreeLibrary)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "FreeLibrary");
    iInfo.loadLibrary = (pLoadLibraryA)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "LoadLibraryA");
    iInfo.virtualAlloc = (pVirtualAlloc)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "VirtualAlloc");
    iInfo.getCurrProc = (pGetCurrentProcess)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "GetCurrentProcess");
    iInfo.writeMemory = (pWriteProcessMemory)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "WriteProcessMemory");
    iInfo.getModInfo = (pGetModuleInformation)GetProcAddress(hNtdll, "K32GetModuleInformation");

    LPVOID lpStubInfo = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, sizeof(IINFO), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!lpStubInfo)
        return 0;

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProc, lpStub, stub, SizeOfStub, NULL))
        return 0;
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProc, lpStubInfo, &iInfo, sizeof(iInfo), NULL))
        return 0;

    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpStub, lpStubInfo, 0, NULL);
    if (!hThread || hThread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    return 1;
}
```

**The code for the DLL to be injected:** http://pastebin.com/8WXxcpu1

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpParam)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello from injectme.dll!", "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

---

The error when running the code above verbatim (assuming you also applied the settings above and have a similar environment) in VS2013's debugger is as follows:

"Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEEA5125D4 in wuauclt.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000007FEEA5125D4."

Upon viewing the process "wuauclt.exe" in Process Hacker, I can clearly see the module was allocated originally (upon being loaded via LoadLibrary) at 0x7fef67c0000. This is shown in the context menu->under miscellaneous->unloaded modules.

Once double-clicking "wuauclt.exe", you can browse over the application's virtual memory to ensure everything is working as it should be. I can confirm for this current session, an RWX memory buffer has been allocated at 0x7fef67c0000 with the exact size of the unloaded module, containing the injectme.dll module. When digging into injectme.dll with CFF Explorer, then entry point RVA seems to be 0x132C, which does not add up, considering the error is much further away in memory. Additionally, I can verify two more RWX memory buffers containing the code injection stub, and information structure. Looking back the information structure probably doesn't need RWX. Anyway, I can't for the life of me figure out the error.

I'm hoping one you may be able to assist me. I am extremely grateful for your time.

Comment: bring code here

Comment: @manetsus my bad, the code has been moved from pastebin. Sorry for any inconveniences.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that you're lacking the fundamental understanding for such a challenging project. You're mixing concepts from rather distinct realms.

Windows itself cares very, very little about the programming language you used in development. Either you get CLR code (.Net) or native code. In this case it's x64. But Windows really doesn't care about `strcpy` or SDL checks. That's for the compiler to deal with, not the OS. Chances are `strcpy` wouldn't even survive, when its code is fully inlined. But you apparently have optimizations turned off, for some strange reason - again a compiler versus OS confusion.

However, Windows *does* care about other concepts that you don't mention. Chiefly those would be ASLR and DEP - Address Space Layout Randomization and Data Execution Prevention. They're techniques to keep hackers out, and you're hacking. So that's not really a surprise.

I'm not sure if by "RWX" you mean Read Write Execute" because you should know that's asking for problems. DEP is inspired by the more aptly named W^X, Write XOR eXecute.

The more likely culprit is ASLR, though. Windows by design tries to load DLL's at unpredicatble addresses, as that eliminates an entire class of hacks. It appears you're assuming a load address, while Windows really is using another address.

A final mistake might be that you're failing to understand *where* the relocations are done. To improve the amount of shareable pages, relocations are done on the Import Address Table, not the code itself. The IAT is a trampoline table, and therefore executable. Your failure might also be a missing IAT.

Comment: First and foremost, I would like to sincerely thank you for the response. Full disclosure, I've only been working on this for a few days now and didn't think about DEP/ASLR.

Comment: (Sorry my previous comment got cut off before I could fully respond)

Comment: Well it appears as though hitting return will automatically post a comment. I'm new to this and going to assume these aren't supposed to be very lengthy. What I'm trying to ask is, moving forward, where do you think I should position my focus? As I understand it, LoadLibrary should perform any and all modifications so that the module passed to it can effectively execute. Once it has a chance to do that, it is simply moved around in memory. It's final resting place is right where it started. The grabs the entry point on-the-fly and doesn't assume. Sorry, but I am left with a bit of confusion.

Comment: @astra: My high-level observation is that you're probably facing an XY problem. The hackery you're trying to pull off is almost certainly not the best way to solve your real problem.

Comment: That's an extremely fair answer. The above is all in an attempt to bypass the detection mechanisms of another process. Moreover, the technique exhibited above will be purely for *pre-injection*. The process attempting to detect my module will analyze all processes currently interacting with it, which is why I require the usage of a seemingly benign host that will act as a front for the final injection. The process attempting to block my module is that of an anti-cheat. Thanks again for all the help, I hope I'm not pestering you with all of my questions.